# Should I spray texture on my drywall repair?

Tags: painting, finishing, repainting, patching-drywall

I'm in the final stages of repairing three holes in my apartment and have just finished sanding down the mud. There is a slight texture on the walls so I picked up some 'orange peel' texture spray but after poking around on DIY, I've seen some answers that recommend just rolling on the paint to match the texture.

What does it all come down to in making this decision?
As a secondary question, at what point do I prime?

[image]

Comment: Many roller applications of flat latex paint leave a slight texture. Is yours more than that? Can you post a picture?

Comment: When I patch holes I usually use a roller for both some primer and a final coat to match the slight texture that walls have obtained from being previously painted with a roller. It depends on how much texture you have already.

Comment: Added photos. See OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current walls are textured with an orange peel texture, then, yes, go ahead and use the 'texture in a can' to replicate.

Every wall in our house is orange peel (blech) so when I created an interior bump out with new sheetrock, I caved in and sprayed to match. I was pleasantly surprised to find the texture-in-a-can is rather easy to apply and seems to do the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are rollers that will texture pre-mix joint compound, they look like ramen-noodles-in-a-tube.  If they are too much, you can smooth down afterwards with a wide taping knife.

Prime after the surface is well dried, 10-15% moisture

[image][image][image]